# Trying to outputting a math equation with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have changeable sized list with integers in it like [2,5,6,9,1] and I am trying to create an addition formula with for loop:

```
z= 1
while z > 0:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(list[i],"+", end=" ")
    z = 0
    print("=",sum(list),end=" ")
```

This is what i am trying and output is:

```
2 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 1 + = 23
```

What should I do if I want to output n integers and n-1 plus signs between integers?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev I am using sum() function for real addition but i want an output like 2 + 3 = 5

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `str.join` that accept an iterable of strings. You need to map each `int` to `str` then join them using the `+` and print the result

```
values = [2, 5, 6, 9, 1]
formula = " + ".join(map(str, values))
print(formula, "=", sum(values))  # 2 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 1 = 23

# Using f-strings
formula = f'{" + ".join(map(str, values))} = {sum(values)}'
print(formula)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
def printfn(alist):
    expr = " + ".join((map(str, alist)))
    sum_val = sum(alist)
    print("{} = {}".format(expr, sum_val))

a = [1,2,3]
printfn(a)
# 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

b = [1,2,3,4]
printfn(b)
# 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `sep=` parameter of `print()` function.

For example:

```
lst = [2,5,6,9,1]

print(*lst, sep=' + ', end=' ')
print('=', sum(lst))
```

Prints:

```
2 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 1 = 23
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the for loop in range( len(list)-1 ) and add a print (list[len(list)-1]) before z=0

```
list = [2,5,6,9,1] 

z= 1
while z > 0:
    for i in range( len(list)-1 ):
         print(list[i],"+", end=" ")
    print (list[len(list)-1],end=" ")
    print("=",sum(list),end=" ")
    z = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), starting with an index of 1

```
>>> l= [2,5,6,9,1]
>>> s = ''
>>> sum_ = 0
>>> for i, v in enumerate(l, 1):
         if i == len(l):
             # If the current item is the length of the list then just append the number at this index, and the final sum
             s += str(v) + ' = ' + str(sum_)
         else:
             # means we are still looping add the number and the plus sign
             s += str(v)+' +
>>> print(s)
2 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 1 = 23
```